# Can't update the symfony CLI

Tags: symfony

I installed Symfony CLI 4-5 months ago and it was generating Symfony projects on version 5.4

Now that the version 6.0 is realeased, I want to update it.

I tried the three cases here https://symfony.com/download but the executables are not working, it keeps generating projects on the older version.

Same thing for `symfony self-update`  that tells me :

```
Checking for Platform.sh CLI for Symfony updates (current version: 3.73.2)
No updates found
```

The only information i can find is about updating a version of Symfony in a specific project.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The symfony CLI will always install the current version (currently 6.0) by default.  Is `symfony new` giving you a different version?  If so then it's probably because you don't have at least php 8.0.2 installed.  I might add the latest version of the CLI is 4.28.1.  Again you probably need to update your php version. Executing `symfony local:php:list` might also be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much, updating PHP to the latest version solved my problem.

Comment: @Cerad please post your comment to the Answer section, Shograti please accept Cerad answer when he posts in the Answer section.

Answer (score 3):

If you installed `symfony-cli` via homebrew, just run `brew upgrade symfony-cli` and you shold be ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

The package on Ubuntu is called `symfony-cli`, so updating it can be done via `apt`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade symfony-cli
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using scoop:

```
scoop update symfony-cli
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit late and obviously you working on a **windwos system**, since you downloaded the executable. All hints in here seem to work for unix systems.

How ever... to update this, find the location where you installed your symfony.
Easiest way to do so, open your environment variable window, check the `path` section for symfony e.g. `c:\Program Files\Symfony` or so, and than go to this folder and simply
**replace this file** with the downloaded executable.

> You may have to restart your console if it was open to let the console recognize the new version.

From now on, if you go to you console and hit `symfony -v` you will be prompted with the new version.

**Additional:**
There is no Symfony-Cli `6.0.0`. Your post was from '22 but untill now ('24) there is still no `6.0.0`.
Latest version currently is `5.8.6`.
Guess most people in here was talking about the Symfony version it self, what is by today `7.0.3`.
These are two diffrent things :)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the Symfony CLI via a package manager, updates are going to be automatic. Just due `sudo apt upgrade` under Ubuntu.

Comment: That's not working for me. It tells me: 
INFO  A new Symfony CLI version is available (5.5.0, currently running 5.4.21).
But as soon as I `sudo apt upgrade` nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I carefully read all the answers and found no word about Linux Fedora.
Well, maybe Fedora is not so popular, but it's great and must have a place here.
I was wondering if the Symfony CLI is as easy to update on a Fedora system as it is on Ubuntu?

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade symfony-cli
```

Or, is it as by Scoop?

```
scoop update symfony-cli
```

These 2 examples are given above by @Afilina and @Amar.

So, if you need to update Symfony CLI on your Fedora system, it's so simple, just run following command in the console

```
sudo dnf update symfony-cli
```

I was happy :) because I didn't find info about it in Symfony docs.